# If a message is from 3 specific users , ignore them

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to know is it possible to stop specific users from using the bot, e.g. user b can not use any commands if they are in the blacklist of the *config.json* . thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you could use

```js
const bannedUsers = ['userid1', 'userid2', 'userid3'];
client.on('message', msg => {
if(bannedUsers.includes(msg.author.id)) return;
//command execution code here
})
```

You will have to put this in all your `client.on('message')` listeners.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show any code, but you could try something like this where you process commands..

```
//when bot receives a message
if (message.author.id === 'blacklisted ids'){
   return;
} else {
   //process commands
}
```

Comment: if you don't plan to blacklist too many users, you could manually add each blacklisted id; otherwise, you could create an array and check `message.author.id` against each blacklisted id in the array using `foreach`.

Comment: No, you use `Array.prototype.includes` to make it faster

Comment: I stand corrected - good to know for the future; thanks for bringing it to my attention.